# Getting Json object as View Model from ajax call & insert that using Entity Framework Core

Tags: ajax, entity-framework-core, asp.net-core-mvc

I get view model data from Ajax with this code:

```
  $.ajax({
            url: '@Url.Action("Create", "Invoice")',
            type: "POST",
            contentType: 'application/json',
            data: JSON.stringify(invoiceViewModel),
            success: function (response) {
                alert(response + " records inserted.")
            },
            error: function (response) {
                alert(response + " records not inserted.")
            }
        });
```

Then I want to insert that into a `Create` action in my controller.

How can I insert using Entity Framework Core?

Comment: `How can I insert using Entity Framework Core?` Have you created required model class(es), database context class and registered your database context with dependency injection? To get started with EF Core in an ASP.NET MVC, please check this doc: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/data/ef-mvc/intro?view=aspnetcore-3.1

Comment: Hi @Ager, any updates about this case?

Answer (score 0):

> I want to insert that into a `Create` action in my controller. How can I insert using Entity Framework Core?

Firstly, you may need to create data model and database context class, and register your database context as a service during application startup.

```
services.AddDbContext<MyDbContext>(options =>
options.UseSqlServer(Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection")));
```

For more information about using EF Core in an ASP.NET MVC, please refer to [this doc about "get started with EF Core in an ASP.NET MVC"](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/data/ef-mvc/intro?view=aspnetcore-3.1).

***Note**: if you have created corresponding model class(es) and registered required service(s), please skip this step.*

After you setup EF Core in your MVC project, the DbContext can then be used in controllers (or other services) through constructor injection.

```
public class InvoiceController : Controller
{
    private readonly MyDbContext _context;

    public InvoiceController(MyDbContext context)
    {
        _context = context;
    }
```

And to add new record to database with following code snippet.

```
if (ModelState.IsValid)
{
    _context.Add(invoice);
    await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
}
```

Besides, to protect your controller from over-posting, please [only include properties in the `[Bind]` attribute](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/data/ef-mvc/crud?view=aspnetcore-3.1#update-the-create-page) that you want to change.